# Update a complex object with mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a Json object structured like this.

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("553e4b0a903fd38019ac2a6a"),
    "id" : 19,
    "monday" : {
        "entrees" : [],
        "viandes" : [],
        "legumes" : [],
        "fromages" : [],
        "desserts" : []
    },
    "thursday" : {
        "entrees" : [],
        "viandes" : [],
        "legumes" : [],
        "fromages" : [],
        "desserts" : []
    },
    "wednesday" : {
        "entrees" : [],
        "viandes" : [],
        "legumes" : [],
        "fromages" : [],
        "desserts" : []
    },
    "tuesday" : {
        "entrees" : [],
        "viandes" : [],
        "legumes" : [],
        "fromages" : [],
        "desserts" : []
    },
    "friday" : {
        "entrees" : [],
        "viandes" : [],
        "legumes" : [],
        "fromages" : [],
        "desserts" : []
    }
}
```

I want to update this object, inserting values in arrays.

I've test different query but my object is never updated.

For example, this query doesn't works fine.

```
self.menucollection.update(
{
    'id' : id
},
{
    $set:{ 'monday':{
        'entrees' : 'toot'
        }
    }   
},
function(err, item){
    callback(err, item);
}
);
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Define "*doesn't works fine*". What do you expect to happen and what happens instead?

Comment: Ok, i want to push a value in monday entrees array, and my query didn't modify my object.

Comment: You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add to an array you have to use [`$push`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/).

Also, access monday/entrees using [dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation).

```
self.menucollection.update({'id': id}, { $push: { 'monday.entrees': 'toot'  }});
```

Comment: Exactly what i was searching for, Thx a lot !